# insert to database with JAX-RS failed

Tags: java, post, jax-rs

I want run POST method with JAX-RS. I tried in POSTMAN but failed.

controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/insertdata")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void insertData(Kasus kasus){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO KASUS " +
            "(KODE_KASUS, NAMA, IS_DELETE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    dbCon = new DBConnection();

    try {
        conn = DBConnection.setDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, kasus.getKodekasus());
        ps.setString(2, kasus.getNama());
        ps.setInt(3, kasus.getIsdelete());
        ps.setString(4, kasus.getCreatedby());
        ps.setDate(5, (Date) kasus.getCreateddate());
        ps.setString(6, kasus.getUpdatedby());
        ps.setDate(7, (Date) kasus.getUpdateddate());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error nih");
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

I tried in postman, add parameter (variabel from model example: kodekasus=89) but failed. in postman "415 unsupported media type". how to fix this problem? or can you give me the reference for this solution? maybe with other way. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like it has nothing to do with databases.  What media type are you POSTing with?

Comment: Have you set `Content-Type: application/json` in Postman?

Comment: I think he is using GET instead of POST

Comment: I already set content-type to application/json

Comment: I using post in postman and controller

Comment: `insertData(@RequestBody Kasus kasus)`

Comment: so, if I use @RequestBody annotation, I use Spring framework, right? I already try but still show same error